# Can't access service outside of Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong, but I can't get docker, on my mac, to properly expose a port.  Here's what I'm doing:

Starting from scratch on the host:

```
> rails -v
Rails 5.0.0.1
> rails new dt6
# ... rails creates a new app
> cd dt6
```

Then I add this Dockerfile at the root of the rails app:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp

EXPOSE 3000
```

Then I build the image and run the container

```
> docker build -t dt6 .

> docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 dt6 rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

That looks like a normal rails/puma "I'm ready to start serving" message.  However, from the host machine, I can't access the rails server:

```
> curl localhost:3000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I know docker's doing *something* with port 3000, because I get a different message for a random port:

```
> curl localhost:3001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3001: Connection refused
```

Notably, the rails server *is* running.  If I attach to the container and hit the rails server from the inside, it works:

```
> docker exec -it dt6_container bash
root@6af33aa9c43b:/myapp# curl localhost:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
#... a normal html response from the rails server
```

TLDR: running a rails server in a docker container, I'm getting an empty response when I access the server from the host machine.  What am I doing wrong if I want to be able to make http requests to the rails server running inside this container from outside of it?

Comment: it seems to me what you do will work fine in Linux, but not in Mac or Windows, which use (more or less) a VM do mimic a Linux

Comment: extract from https://www.viget.com/articles/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide `curl $(boot2docker ip):49153` (this is an example)

Comment: Are you using Docker for Mac or Docker Machine/Docker Toolbox?

Comment: I'm using Docker for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]` after `EXPOSE 3000` to your docker file.